# Mutually Exclusive Checkbox using dat.GUI.js API

Tags: user-interface

I would like to know how to create mutually exclusive checkboxes using dat.GUI.js. API Link: http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage.

I have created a jsfiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/dEbRg/ ] to implement mutually exclusive checkbox. But it has some issues.

Step 1: When i click CheckBox2 its working as expected.

Step 2: when i click CheckBox1 its not getting checked.

Can someone guide me how to fix it or give a link where i can get answers for questions regarding dat.GUI.js

Comment: Works for me, although I have to click again (seems to want a double-click?). Also, why not just use the normal controls for the iow radio button list.

Comment: Need to double click and thats what the issue. Ideally i need that to work with a double click. I think radio button is not available in dat.GUI.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code in your jsFiddle as follows:

```
// dat.gui controls
var view = this;
view.CheckBox1 = true;
view.CheckBox2 = false;


var gui = new dat.GUI();
var CB1Controller = gui.add(view, 'CheckBox1').listen();
CB1Controller.onChange(function(value){
        view.CheckBox1 = true;
        view.CheckBox2 = false;
});

var CB2Controller = gui.add(view, 'CheckBox2').listen();
CB2Controller.onChange(function(value){
        view.CheckBox1 = false;
        view.CheckBox2 = true;
});
```

The boolean toggle code you were previously using would not generalize well to more than two selections.  Also, this version of the code will enforce exactly one checkbox being selected at all times -- zero selections will not be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works !. Can we have zero selection also be a possibility with out breaking the functionality ?

Comment: How about using the same code, but adding another option at the bottom called "none of the above"?

Comment: Using 'none of the above' seems to be inappropriate to me...!!